# php script in elementor

Tags: php

How would one add a php script like the one below in elementor?  This page tells you to create a shortcode [reference](https://wpcodeus.com/how-to-add-php-code-to-elementor/#:%7E:text=%20How%20To%20Add%20PHP%20Code%20to%20Elementor,echo%20using%20this%20solution%3B%20it%20can...%20More%20) add it to a functions.php file and call it using a shortcode block.  But where is this functions.php file?

```
<?php

//if the submit button is clicked, follow logic to insert record
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $insert_value = 1;

    //make a database connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'motordata');    

    //prepared statement to insert the record
    $stmt_insert_record = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MotorOn (command) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt_insert_record->bind_param("i", $insert_value);
    $stmt_insert_record->execute();
    $stmt_insert_record->close();
}
?>

<!-- Form that will submit to the document's address ie. the same page-->
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Shutdown" style="background-color: red;">
</form>
```

Comment: functions.php is a file in your theme, if it does not exist then you will need to create it. You will want to create a child theme to avoid all your changes being lost when you theme updates. You could also put your shortcode in a plugin file instead. Note that the code you shared isn't enough to create a shortcode. You'll also need to ask Elementor support for help with using shortcodes in Elementor as Elementor/3rd party  plugin/theme dev support is offtopic here

Answer (score 0):

Your functions.php file is located at Appearance > Theme Editor.

However, my suggestion is to create a custom plugin or find a ready-made plugin to handle your form submission data. Here's a link to more information about this: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-plugin-in-5-minutes/